# Prevent Firebird's default instance from starting

Tags: windows, firebird, startup, windows-8

I want temporarily to use another named instance. Can I prevent the default instance from starting when the PC starts? I am using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options

1. Manually change the startup type of the service
2. Remove (and optionally reinstall) the service

## Manually change the startup type of the service

You can disable it in the Services configuration. Use Windows-key+R or open run from the start menu, enter `services.msc`, find the Firebird instance (*Firebird Server - DefaultInstance*), right click, *Properties* and change the Startup type from *Automatic* to *Manual*:

[image]

## Remove (and optionally reinstall) the service

You can also remove the service entry completely, to do this, you need to start the command prompt as Administrator. Under Windows 10 this would be Windows-key+X, A. I believe this doesn't work under Windows 8.1, there you may need to use Start, search for `cmd` or *Command prompt*, right click and select *Run as Administrator*.

In the command prompt go to the location of your Firebird install (or for Firebird 2.5 and lower, its `bin`-folder), and run

```
instsvc stop
instsvc remove
```

If you want to have the service entry, but just not automatically started, you can reinstall it with:

```
instsvc install -demand
```

This will install the service with startup type *Manual* (just using `instsvc install` or `instsvc -auto` will install it as *Automatic*); see `instsvc` for more information.